# Lost some hats - by design or by error?

Tags: bug, winter-bash-2020

I appear to have lost some hats: At the beginning I got 5 or 6 secret hats (obviously I have no idea for what) but that count suddenly went down to 4. I might have thought that I mis-remembered if I wasn't currently wearing one of the lost ones:

[image: Wearing a hat I'm missing]

As you see that Disciple hat is not in the collection. Furthermore, the "You earned this hat on" list for it is empty.

Thus, ... are hats sometimes denied after earning them by design or is this a glitch?

Comment: Yes, I remember I also had balalaika. Ok, but fun that I can still wear that hat. ;)